Replace Spaces with New Lines in Comma-Separated Number Lines
I have a list like following:
\u042f 12,197,051
\ube44\ud574 93,721,409
HUMAN 45,754,677
Overwatch 43,437,031 OVERWATE

Now I want to replace spaces with new lines in Comma-Separated number lines like following results:
\u042f
12,197,051
\ube44\ud574
93,721,409
HUMAN
45,754,677
Overwatch
43,437,031
OVERWATE

I tried following regex:
Find What: (^\h*)(.*?)(\h*,.*$)
Replace With: \1\2\n\3

But it not working good and provide me following results:
\u042f 12
,197,051
\ube44\ud574 93
,721,409
HUMAN 45
,754,677
Overwatch 43
,437,031 OVERWATE

Where is my regex problem?

Each line of your sample input contains a number with comma. So just replace \h+ with \n. Or do you have other lines without comma in your input too, where you don't want spaces to be replaced? If so, please provide a better sample.

If you want to replace leading spaces before comma separated numbers:
\h+(\d+(?:,\d+)+)(\h+)?

The pattern matches:

\h+ Match 1 or more horizontal whitespace characters
(\d+(?:,\d+)+) Capture group 1, match 1+ digits and repeat 1 or more times a comma and again 1+ digits
(\h+)? Optional group 2, match 1 or more horizontal whitespace characters

See a regex demo
In the replacement a newline followed by the group 1 value, and if there is a group 2 value append another newline using a conditional:
 \n$1(?{2}\n)



NOTE : In Search / Find Pop up menu Please select Extended (\n, \r) checkbox, if display.

You have to find space character & replace it with \n OR \r\n character which is used for new line.
Try this solution :
Find what : space character
Replace with : \n

